# Wordpress 401 error: rest_forbidden. Sorry, you are not allowed to make proxied oEmbed requests

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, fastcgi, windows-server

I'm getting 401 error on the following URL call on my Wordpress hosted on Windows IIS server:

https://example.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/proxy?url=https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/img.jpg

```
{
"code": "rest_forbidden",
"message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to make proxied oEmbed requests.",
"data": {
    "status": 401
}
```

}

The above URL is called by the Elementor gallery widget when I want to set an external image for it.

Although, the following URL is working on my Wordpress site:

https://example.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0?url=https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/img.jpg

```
{
"namespace": "oembed\/1.0",
"routes": {
    "\/oembed\/1.0": {
        "namespace": "oembed\/1.0",
        "methods": ["GET"],
        "endpoints": [{
                "methods": ["GET"],
                "args": {
                    "namespace": {
                        "default": "oembed\/1.0",
                        "required": false
                    },
                    "context": {
                        "default": "view",
                        "required": false
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "_links": {
            "self": [{
                    "href": "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-json\/oembed\/1.0"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "\/oembed\/1.0\/embed": {
        "namespace": "oembed\/1.0",
        "methods": ["GET"],
        "endpoints": [{
                "methods": ["GET"],
                "args": {
                    "url": {
                        "description": "The URL of the resource for which to fetch oEmbed data.",
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "uri",
                        "required": true
                    },
                    "format": {
                        "default": "json",
                        "required": false
                    },
                    "maxwidth": {
                        "default": 600,
                        "required": false
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "_links": {
            "self": [{
                    "href": "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-json\/oembed\/1.0\/embed"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "\/oembed\/1.0\/proxy": {
        "namespace": "oembed\/1.0",
        "methods": ["GET"],
        "endpoints": [{
                "methods": ["GET"],
                "args": {
                    "url": {
                        "description": "The URL of the resource for which to fetch oEmbed data.",
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "uri",
                        "required": true
                    },
                    "format": {
                        "description": "The oEmbed format to use.",
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "json",
                        "enum": ["json", "xml"],
                        "required": false
                    },
                    "maxwidth": {
                        "description": "The maximum width of the embed frame in pixels.",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "default": 600,
                        "required": false
                    },
                    "maxheight": {
                        "description": "The maximum height of the embed frame in pixels.",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "required": false
                    },
                    "discover": {
                        "description": "Whether to perform an oEmbed discovery request for unsanctioned providers.",
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": true,
                        "required": false
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "_links": {
            "self": [{
                    "href": "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-json\/oembed\/1.0\/proxy"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
"_links": {
    "up": [{
            "href": "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-json\/"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

PHP: 7.4.16
Wordpress: 5.6.2
Windows Server: 2019

Comment: Please check if current user can make a proxy oEmbed request.

Comment: @samwu How can I check it?

Comment: This link should help you. [https://medium.com/@andrewoons/how-to-make-proxy-requests-with-postman-through-eg-quotaguard-e317ee62f7ae](https://medium.com/@andrewoons/how-to-make-proxy-requests-with-postman-through-eg-quotaguard-e317ee62f7ae).

Comment: @samwu It seems the current user (admin) doesn't have such permission. But I couldn't find on Google how to give it the required permission in Wordpress.